# How do i remove "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" from the output text?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
text2 = string.Format("[B](No Change)[/B]");
```

The output comes out as:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: (No Change)
```

How can I remove the `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:` from my output?

Comment: Why are you using `string.Format` without a format string or arguments? There is not enough code and information in your question to make it answerable.

Comment: Where are you seeing this output?

Comment: text2 = "(No Change)"; ?

Comment: Try this; `text2 = text2.Replace("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:", "");` after you define `text2` as `string.Format("[B](No Change)[/B]");`. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 4):

Well a wild guess, but I think what **you are trying to print is not the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx) property of the textbox, instead the whole textbox**.

Suppose you have:

```
TextBox1.Text = string.Format("[B](No Change)[/B]");;
Console.Write(TextBox1);
```

Then you will get the output.

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: [B](No Change)[/B]
```

What you probably need to do is to use [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx) property.

```
Console.Write(TextBox1.Text);
```

This will give you the assigned text and will exclude. `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:` part

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a guess here but are you trying to make "No change" appear as bold text?  In that case, you can modify the textbox font itself rather than try and format your string.

```
text2.text = "No change";
text2.Font = new Font(text2.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

If that's not what you were trying to do then sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to add Text
text2.Text = string.Format("[B](No Change)[/B]");